# SQL query to set posts in bulk based on the post content

Tags: database, query, mysql, sql

I have thousands of offline links in my posts, and I'd like to set them all to draft. I know the links are in the format example.com/fileX. So I needed a SQL query to search the post content and whatever post that contain that url will be set to draft.

I think this might be a good start:

```
UPDATE tb_posts 
SET post_status = 'draft' 
WHERE
```

But I don't know to do the search inside the WHERE clause. I intend to use ARI Adminer Plugin to edit the database.

Comment: What do you mean by the format "example.com/fileX"? Do you mean the Links are always starting with "example.com/file" followed by a number, a string of characters? Please elaborate...

Comment: It doesn't matter if it has a string. If the search contains example.com will be enough to set it to draft! Note that I'll not change anything on the post content, only to the post_status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into MySQL Wildcards.

The correct MySQL Query for your search should be

```
WHERE tb_posts.post_content LIKE "%example.com%"
```

You should also be sure that you only target published posts (in contrast to nav_menu_items, revisions etc). Expand your WHERE with this:

```
AND tb_posts.post_type IN ('post','page',*All Posttypes you use additionally*) AND tb_posts.post_status = 'publish'
```

So your complete Query should look like this (assuming that you only use posts and pages):

```
UPDATE tb_posts 
SET post_status = 'draft' 
WHERE post_content LIKE "%example.com%"
AND post_type IN ('post','page')
AND post_status = 'publish'
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: A genius is a genius. Thank you! Worked perfectly.